# Using PHP rather than JSON as output in instant search script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a Google Instant style search script written in jQuery which I want to pull results from a PHP script. I know my script currently needs JSON as the output but I want it to output PHP generated HTML instead. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var keyword=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='http://www.SITEURL.com/search.php?action=SEARCH&keyword='+keyword+;
        window.location.hash=keyword;

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"jsonp",
            success:function(response){
                $("#result").html('');
                if(response.SearchResponse.Web.Results.length){
                    $.each(response.SearchResponse.Web.Results, function(i,data){
                        var title=data.Title;
                        var dis=data.Description;
                        var url=data.Url;
                        var final="<div class='webresult'><div class='title'><a href='"+url+"'>"+title+"</a></div><div class='desc'>"+dis+"</div><div class='url'>"+url+"</div></div>";
                        $("#result").append(final);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
dataType:"html",
```

In your $.ajax call. The result will be returned as plain text, so if you just want to display it you can

```
success:function(response){
   $("#result").html(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a single:

```
$("#result").load("filename.html #elementid_inside_filename");
```

Would suffice. (unless the file is in another domain)